# Registering Generic Interfaces and classes with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

My current Autofac config is working to resolve my ApiControllers in a WebApi.

Where I'm struggling is, I'm attempting to create a 'BaseApiController' with generic constructor parameters, but getting exception:

> No constructors on type 'Service`1[WorldRegion]' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.

Here is the code structure:

```
public interface IEntityKey { }
public class WorldRegion : IEntityKey { }
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntityKey { }
public interface IService<T> where T : IEntityKey { }
public abstract class Service<T> : IService<T> where T : IEntityKey { }
public interface IWorldRegionService : IService<WorldRegion> { }
public class WorldRegionService : Service<WorldRegion>, IWorldRegionService
{
    private readonly IRepository<WorldRegion> _repository;
}
```

WORKING API Controller:

```
public class WorldRegionsController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly IWorldRegionService _worldRegionService;
    private readonly ICultureService _cultureService;

    public WorldRegionsController(IWorldRegionService worldRegionService, ICultureService cultureService)
    {
        _worldRegionService = worldRegionService;
        _cultureService = cultureService;
    }
}
```

WORKING Autofac config:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config, IAppBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    RegisterTypes(builder);

    var container = builder.Build();
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
}

public static void RegisterTypes(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    // Context
    builder.RegisterType<DataContext>().As<IDataContext>().InstancePerRequest();
    // UOW
    builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
    // Repositories
    builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerRequest();
    // Services
    builder.RegisterType<CultureService>().As<ICultureService>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<WorldRegionService>().As<IWorldRegionService>().InstancePerRequest();
}
```

Here is the generic ATTEMPT:

```
// BaseApiController
public abstract class BaseApiController<T> : ApiController where T : IEntityKey

{
    protected readonly IService<T> _service;
    protected readonly ICultureService _cultureService;
    public BaseApiController(IService<T> service, ICultureService cultureService)
    {
        _service = service;
        _cultureService = cultureService;
    }
}

// ApiController
public class WorldRegionsController : BaseApiController<WorldRegion>
{
    public WorldRegionsController(
        IService<WorldRegion> service, ICultureService cultureService)
            : base(service, cultureService) {}
}

// Added to Autofac config
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service<>)).As(typeof(IService<>)).InstancePerRequest();
// Removed
builder.RegisterType<WorldRegionService>().As<IWorldRegionService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

With this change, I'm getting the exception message noted above (in yellow).  I think I'm missing something in the Autofac config, just not sure what. Maybe include/register/add 'WorldRegion' somehow.

How should I register my types ?

Comment: You are registering `RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service<>)).As(typeof(IService<>))` but `Service<T>` itself is abstract, so Autofac can't create it.

Answer (score 5):

Your controller expect a `IService<WorldRegion>`. *Autofac* find the following registration for this service :

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service<>)).As(typeof(IService<>)).InstancePerRequest();
```

So it tries to create a `Service<WorldRegion>` which is not possible because `Service<T>` is an abstract class.

Don't forget that a `IWorldRegionService` is a `IService<WorldRegion>` but a `IService<WorldRegion>` is not a `IWorldRegionService`.

You don't want to register a generic service but want to register all children as a `IService<T>`, you can do this by using the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` method with the `AsClosedTypedOf`

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(this.GetAssemblies())
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IService<>));
```

Read [Autofac documentation - Assembly scanning](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html) for more information and how to properly implement the `GetAssemblies` method in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I tried removing the abstract from `Service<T>`, that didn't work, same error.  Then I read the Autofac docs and searched around, and I found something similar to [Cyril's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42954006) that works:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Service<>).Assembly)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I tried Cyril's implementation of `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes()` but `this.GetAssemblies()` wasn't available. I had to use the full path and this also works:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IService<>));
```

To note, using either `builder.RegisterTypes()`, the `Service<T>` can still be abstract. And just to test, I changed WorldRegionService to abstract, and that DID NOT work.

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK..!!!! Must remove 'abstract' from this class.
public abstract class WorldRegionService {}
```

So both above `builder.RegisterTypes()` work.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15610420)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean..?  I rarely post questions so I'm not familiar with protocol.  But what I posted is the response to Cyril's post, and confirming what worked and what doesn't.  This is the final and complete answer.